# Starting computer without CPU or with unsupported CPU can damage anything?

Tags: cpu, diagnostic

I'm building a vintage PC and It's not working.

I'm using a Pentium 100 ([A80502100](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Pentium/Intel-Pentium%20100%20-%20A80502-100%20(A80502100).html)) with a EPoX [EP-MVP3G5](http://www.epox.com/product.asp?ID=EP-MVP3G5). All is powered by a new [Corsair cx400w](http://www.corsair.com/products/cx/default.aspx).

I've setted the VCore switches on the motherboard to 3.2V (it's the max the mobo supports), bus clock to 66 mhz and multiplier to 2X (last 2 with 2 jumpers).

When I power up, the HDDs starts, the power supply fan spins but the CPU fan isn't moving at all (when I power ON/OFF I see it move just a little bit). Also the screen stay black, no POST beep, nothing...

This Pentium CPU isn't listed in the supported CPU list (found that out after testing). I will buy a Pentium 133 which is in the supported list to do more tests. I also tested the PC without any CPU at all with the exact same results.

Meanwhile I wanted to know if I could have damaged something in my new (old) PC with all those tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you *could* of damaged something, it is impossible to say "everything is fine" when you have not tested it in a working situation.

My advise to you would be to get components which are all on the compatibility list / guaranteed to work with it and then start tweaking it after you know it works.

Without seeing it or knowing a lot more, it is really hard to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say it's your ram.  If you are using more than one stick, try taking one of them out, if it still doesn't work, put the other one in.  If you're only using one stick, find another.

Comment: And by that I mean it's either incompatible or faulty.

Comment: This is not necessarily the problem but it is CERTAINLY possible.

Comment: I know that.  Just a hunch. ;)